# how to generate custom id in PHP using input info and database data?

Tags: php

how do i generate an ID  by combining the first 3 letters of the last name followed by time of registration (hhmmss) and date of registration (ddMMMyyyy)?

ex. Jackson, Michael
September 21, 2000 [4:07:11 PM]

ID: JAC-160711-21SEP2000

only thing ive search of is the code below. can i substr a POST method and pass it to a variable?

```
<?php


function NewGuid() { 
    $s = strtoupper(md5(uniqid(rand(),true))); 
    $guidText = 
        substr($s,0,8) . '-' . 
        substr($s,8,4) . '-' . 
        substr($s,12,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,16,4). '-' . 
        substr($s,20); 
    return $guidText;
}


$Guid = NewGuid();
echo $Guid;
echo "<br>";

?>
```

Comment: So, what is the output you get?

Comment: "substr a post method"? Huh? you can substr any string in php. doesn't matter WHERE that string came from.

Comment: it generates random numbers and is substr per parts. 
like substr($s,0,8) gets random 8 numbers and is combined with ' - ' with other substr.

output. BF0DD597-C496-81E5-82AF-A6420DFE9165

but what i want to know is how to substr or get from a string in a database and generate it as an id.

Comment: @MarcB how to substr data in the database then use it as part of a  generated id?

Comment: What about you query said data from the database? What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the info via POST you can do it like this:

```
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];    
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$id = substr($last_name, 0, 3).'-'.date('His').'-'.date('dMY');
print $id;
```

This works assuming your first and last names are given separately, if you don't then you have to parse it and it can be a little messy.

Comment: thanks you! it works. im a bit new to php  ,now i just have to store the generated id to the db.  thanks again:)